# Is there any way to find out the exact requested URL in ServletRequest if that URL contains path variables?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, servlet-3.0

For example, if my URL mapped to is `/app/service/{id}` when I am calling `request.getRequestURI()` is giving me something like `/app/service/10` which I want in the same format specified in my controller class. Is there any way to achieve the same?

Comment: Have you tried: String restOfTheUrl = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);

Comment: @mohitsharma Yes, It is coming as null. I have debug and check all the attributes are null for the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `HttpServletRequest request`

You can use
    [request.getRequestURL();](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29)

OR you can use

```
String path = request.getPathInfo();
String[] pathParts = pathInfo.split("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumming you're using `HttpServletRequest request`

```java
request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE)
```

Comment: I am using HttpServletRequest only, but the attributes are null. Note that I am testing it through swagger.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `Filter` instead, using `HandlerInterceptor` worked for me. So my previous code was

```
public class MyInterceptor implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter( ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain ) 
               throws IOException, ServletException {
                 final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
                 String url = req.getRequestURI();
                //this was giving me /app/service/10
        }
```

Now I have changed my code to

```
 public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler )
                throws Exception
        {
           String url = request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
          //this gives me /app/service/{id}
        }

    }
```